# Unable to load data from a json file in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, store

I've trying to get the sencha touch 2 data management examples to work but with no use. Here is the code of a simple model and store that are not working (getCount returns 0).

```
Ext.define('MyClient.model.Product', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    config:{
        fields:['name', 'image'],
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            url:'http://localhost/st2/Projets/my-client-sencha/data/products.json',
            reader:{
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:'products',
                successProperty:'success'
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyClient.store.ProductsStore', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    config:{
        model:'MyClient.model.Product',
        autoLoad:true,
        autoSync:true
    }
});
```

In the launch function I have these lines:

```
        var prod = Ext.create('MyClient.store.ProductsStore');
        prod.load();
        alert(prod.getCount());
```

And finally here's my products.json:

```
[

    {
        "name":"test"
    }
]
```

I'm not getting any errors in the console but still the getCount always returns 0. Can use some help here please.

EDIT: wrong JSON, not working with this neither:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "products": [

        {
            "name":"test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your setting rootProperty:'products', your json has to be like

```
{
    products: [

        {
            "name":"test"
        }
    ]
}
```

if you do not want to change server response remover rootProperty from config.

have a look at [Json Reader doc](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json)

Ahh... you forgot about asyn nature of the load()....

```
var prod = Ext.create('MyClient.store.ProductsStore');
prod.load(function ( ){
    alert(prod.getCount());
});
```

Notice that it prod.load() is using only for testing purposes, as far you have set property autoLoad: true.

In your snippet the loader would make 2 similar calls.

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Yeah I tried that too and not working neither, etill getting 0

Comment: Try to move proxy config from model to store. Proxy by model is necessary only if you do model.load()/save() etc, which is not bound to any store.

Comment: Well I removed the prod.load() and everything is working perfectly now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('MyBizilinkms.model.Customer', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    identifier:'uuid',
    fields: [
    'CustId',
    'EMail',
    'Title',
    'FName', 
    'MdInitial', 
    'LName', 
    'PhnNum', 
    'SecondPhnNo', 
    'DOB', 
    'Address', 
    'SecondAddress', 
    'City',
    'State', 
    'Zip', 
    'Country', 
    'RecieveEmail',
    'IsSaveonServer',
    { 
        name: 'Full_Name',
        type:'string',
        convert:function(v, rec) {
            return rec.data.FName + " " + rec.data.LName;
        }
    }],
    validations: [
    {
        type: 'format',   
        name: 'EMail', 
        matcher: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/, 
        message:"Valid Email Required"
    },
    {
        name: 'PhnNum',             
        type : 'custom',
        message : "Valid Phone required",
        validator : function(config, value, model) {
            var reg = /^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
            return reg.test(value);
        }            
    },
    {
        name: 'SecondPhnNum',             
        type : 'custom',
        message : "Valid 2nd Phone required",
        validator : function(config, value, model) {
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(value)) {
                var reg = /^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
                return reg.test(value)
            }
            return true;
        }            
    },
    {
        type: 'presence', 
        name: 'FName', 
        message : "First Name is required"
    },
    {
        type: 'presence', 
        name: 'LName', 
        message : "Last Name is required"
    }, 
    {
        type: 'presence', 
        name: 'Address', 
        message : "Address is required"
    },
    {
        type: 'presence', 
        name: 'City', 
        message : "City is required"
    },
    {
        name: 'State',             
        type : 'custom',
        message : "Valid State required",
        validator : function(config, value, model) {
            var reg = /^(AK|AL|AR|AZ|CA|CO|CT|DC|DE|FL|GA|HI|IA|ID|IL|IN|KS|KY|LA|MA|MD|ME|MI|MN|MO|MS|MT|NB|NC|ND|NH|NJ|NM|NV|NY|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VA|VT|WA|WI|WV|WY)$/i;
            if(Ext.isEmpty(value))
                value = '00'
            var state = value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");

            return reg.test(state)
        }            
    },
    {
        name: 'Zip',             
        type : 'custom',
        message : "Valid Zip required",
        validator : function(config, value, model) {
            var reg = /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/;
            return reg.test(value)
        }            
    },
    {
        type: 'presence', 
        name: 'Country', 
        message : "Country is required"
    }
    ]       
},
getFullName: function() {
    return this.get('FName') + '' + this.get( 'LName');
}
});
```

Comment: This is helping code for everyone to write to exact model with validator in sencha. if you are want to share your suggesions,,then shre me... my email addrss is given bellow...   tasawar.appsgenii@gmail.com